# How to apply function to list of options in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

Suppose I have a function `f: (Int, Int, Int) => String`. I can easily apply it to three parameters of type `Option[Int]`:

```
def foo(f: (Int, Int, Int) => String,
        ox: Option[Int],
        oy: Option[Int],
        oz: Option[Int]): Option[String] = ox <*> (oy <*> (oz <*> f.curried.some))
```

Suppose now that I need to apply `f` to the first three elements of list `ois: List[Option[Int]]`. For example:

```
List() => None
List(1.some, 2.some) => None
List(1.some, None, 2.some, 3.some) => None
List(1.some, 2.some, 3.some, 4.some) => Some(f(1, 2, 3))
List(1.some, 2.some, 3.some, None) => Some(f(1, 2, 3))
```

How would you implement it ?

Comment: If the fourth element of the list is None, what result do you want? With sequence, you get None.

Comment: @DidierDupont Thank you. I was wrong. For `List(1.some, 2.some, 3.some, None)` I need to get `Some(f(1, 2, 3))`. I will update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Option`, `take`, `flatten`, and `collect` together for a pretty clean version:

```
def foo(f: (Int, Int, Int) => String, ois: List[Option[Int]]) = 
    Option(ois.take(3).flatten) collect {
        case List(a, b, c) => f(a, b, c)
}
```

`ois.take(3).flatten` will only match `List(a,b,c)` if the first three elements are `Some`.  You wrap the variable in `Option` to enable the desired `collect` semantics (such that the partial function miss will return `None`, and the return of the partial function will be wrapped in `Some`).

Comment: Thank you. It looks pretty neat ! I am just wondering what if I have `List[A[Int]]` where `A` is another applicative.

Comment: @Michael You can replace `Option(ois.take(3).flatten)` with `ois.take(3).sequence`

Comment: This is a version for generic typeclasses: `def foo[A[_] : Applicative](f: (Int, Int, Int) => String, ois: List[A[Int]]): A[String] = ois.take(3).sequence.map { case List(a,b,c) => f(a,b,c) }` (There is no `collect` on applicatives, but `map` is enough)